# How to install fedora 12 iso file?

Tags: linux, fedora

i downloaded Fedora 12 iso file. how can i create a bookable disc from an iso file and install

Please suggest me how to install Fedora 12 in a machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Well on windows, you can use imageburn to burn the [iso](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/G/Burning+ISO+Images+with+ImgBurn) into a cd. If you have linux, brasero and k3b do the same thing. remember that you want a cd with the iso contents, not a cd with the iso in it.

Alternately assuming you have a USB key and the image is of a livecd, you can use unetbootin or rufus to make a bootable usb to do the install

Oh, and for god's sake, RTFA. I believe fedora [should have a guide on how to install it](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Installation_Guide/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Fedora-specific tool for creating live USB drives - [Fedora Media Writer](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) (Windows/Mac/Linux). Fedora Media Writer (formerly Fedora Live USB Creator) is a free and opensource tool for easily installing live operating systems onto USB flash drives.

#### Features

- Cross-platform (available for Windows, Mac and Linux)
- There is no need to deal with formatting or partitioning your USB flash drive.
- Automatically detects all removable devices
- Supports automatically downloading various Fedora releases
- Persistent storage creation, to save all documents created and modifications made to the system
- Checksum verification
- Not limited to Fedora releases, supports custom images

[image]