# How to install Fedora from an .iso file?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install fedora 12 iso file?](https://superuser.com/questions/94264/how-to-install-fedora-12-iso-file)

I just downloaded Fedora from [here](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kde/).

How do I install Fedora from the .iso file that is downloaded?
Also, I have Vista already installed on my machine.

Comment: Okay, I fell for the "answer first and then find dupes" myself: http://superuser.com/questions/94264/how-to-install-fedora-12-iso-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, assuming the machine you're installing it on has an optical drive, is burning the ISO to a CD. ISO is the standard for CD/DVD images, so whatever burning program you're using should be willing to handle .iso files.

Then restart the computer and boot it from the disc, this will fire up the Fedora installer.

Comment: can this be done in someway using Daemon tools? I mean without actually burning the .iso file onto a CD?

Comment: @eSKay: You can put it on a USB drive if you don't want do waste a disc. See http://docs.fedoraproject.org/install-guide/f12/en-US/html/ch-new-users.html#sn-making-media for more. There might be ways to do some weird reboot-without-rebooting tricks, but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be worth the pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can BURN the ISO file you've just downloaded with WinV to a CD or DVD and boot it from there.

That's the easiest way, in my opinion.