# How can I boot Fedora from an ISO file in GRUB 2?

Tags: multi-boot, fedora, bootloader, bootable-media, grub2

**TL;DR:** What formation of GRUB2 menuentry / linux kernel boot options do I need in order to boot Fedora using the iso as its filesystem / source / get anything to work that way, and not simply burn it to a disc, set the ISO to a VM's virtual optical drive, or empty the ISO's contents into a separate drive partition and chainload into that?

### Background / Research

I need a menuentry that works.  I've tried a bunch and can't remember what place I stand at.  It's been a while..

This link might have almost helped, but there's no further information in that section: [Ubuntu Documentation - Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples#Fedora](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples#Fedora)

These links do not help, as I do not want to store every distro/tool I need to individual media:

- [SuperUser - How to install Fedora from an .iso file? [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/111251/how-to-install-fedora-from-an-iso-file)
- [SuperUser - How to install fedora 12 iso file?](https://superuser.com/questions/94264/how-to-install-fedora-12-iso-file)
- [Ask Fedora - How to boot Fedora ISO with grub2?? thx](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/36228/how-to-boot-fedora-iso-with-grub2-thx/)

This link seems to mention the `root=` parameter several times, and would be a helpful place to look, but I have not been able to use it to understand and fix my situation: [fedora - Common kernel problems](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_kernel_problems?rd=KernelCommonProblems)

An old iteration of my boot configuration with multiple items that doesn't look as messy: [GitHubGist - Pysis868/grub.cfg](https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c)

I believe I have taken out the '0's in the Fedora entry for the required boot files, and have gotten past that point in my progress.

I think I'm at a point of trying to get the root filesystem set-up correctly.
Right now I receive the errors:

```
...
[  <system_Step_time> dracut-initqueue[604]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs'
...<below message repeated>...
[  <system_Step_time> dracut-initqueue[604]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
[  <system_Step_time> dracut-initqueue[604]: Warning: Could not boot.
[  <system_Step_time> dracut-initqueue[604]: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist
[  <system_Step_time> dracut-initqueue[604]: /dev/root does not exist
        Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
```

The 'ntfs' error may just be from the system trying to read from another partition.  The boot files are all located on the first partition, in a FAT32 filesystem (command and output from another one of my Linux-based VMs):

```
username@localhost > sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 57.9 GiB, 62176362496 bytes, 121438208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x745111c0

Device     Boot     Start       End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048  82915264 82913217 39.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2        82915265 121436159 38520895 18.4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        82915328  89982975  7067648  3.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6        89982976 117438463 27455488 13.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       117440512 121436159  3995648  1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

From inside the rescue shell:

```
dracut:/# ls /dev/s* -1
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda5
/dev/sda6
/dev/sda7
/dev/sg0
/dev/sg1
/dev/snapshot
/dev/sr0
/dev/stderr
/dev/stdin
/dev/stdout

/dev/shm:
lldpad.state
dracut:/# fdisk
sh: fdisk: command not found
```

`Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso/isolinux/grub.conf` relevant excerpt:

```
title Start Fedora-Workstation-Live 25
    findiso
    kernel @KERNELPATH@ @ROOT@ rd.live.image quiet
    initrd @INITRDPATH@
```

`Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso/isolinux/isolinux.cfg` relevant excerpt:

```
menu label ^Start Fedora-Workstation-Live 25
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-25-1-3 rd.live.image quiet
```

I looked inside of Unetbootin's installer, but didn't find any useful files yet.

`LinuxLive USB Creator 2.9.4\sources\LiLi\Boot_Menus.au3` relevant excerpt:

```
         & @LF & "label live" _
         & @LF & "  menu label " & Translate("Live Mode") _
         & @LF & "  kernel "&$vmlinuz_file _
         & @LF & "  append initrd="&$initrd_file&" root=UUID=" & $uuid & " rootfstype=vfat ro "&$liveimg_text&" quiet rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0" _
         & @LF & "  menu default"
```

Relevant excerpt from my current messy test block in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry "TEST Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3 TEST 2" {
  set isofile="$linuxPath/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso"
  loopback loop "$isofile"
  # linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-25-1-3 rd.live.image quiet
  # linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz root=UUID="2016-11-15-22-03-09-00" rootfstype=vfat ro rd.live.image quiet rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0
  linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename="$isofile" rootfstype=vfat ro rd.live.image quiet rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0
  # linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz root=CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-25-1-3 rd.live.image quiet
  initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```

Link related to the topic, just doesn't cover Fedora specifically: [SuperUser - grub: boot from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso)

I don't know if this helps, but I think the `search` command is neat: [askubuntu - How to boot from an .iso file in GRUB2? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24903/how-to-boot-from-an-iso-file-in-grub2/237766#237766)

I would not be using this from the hard disk and the partition's filesystem directly.

This did not specifically cover the `root=` boot/kernel parameter, but it does seem to have template formats that resemble its value under the `9.1.4. Specifying the Installation Method` section: [Fedora Documentation - Chapter 9. Boot Options](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/ap-admin-options.html)

**Installation method - Option format**

- CD or DVD drive   - `repo=cdrom:device`
- Hard Drive    - `repo=hd:device/path`
- HTTP Server   - `repo=http://host/path`
- FTP Server    - `repo=ftp://username:password@host/path`
- NFS Server    - `repo=nfs:server:/path`
- ISO images on an NFS Server   - `repo=nfsiso:server:/path`

Actually, reading into the help bubble that is coupled with the link to the "Boot Options" page this time, tells me I can read the `/usr/share/doc/kernel-doc-version/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt` file from the `kernel-doc` package for the full list of kernel options.

That package was not installed on my F25 system by default, and I also did not see it in the repository.  I only saw `kernel-` packages mainly with the suffixes `core`, `PAE`, `header`, `modules`, `debug`, `devel`, `rpm`, and `tools`.

#### Environment

Host: Windows 10 Pro x64

Hyperviser: Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.22 with Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack 5.1.22 ran as administrator for direct disk access

[VM Specs.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p385.png)

[TestPhysicalDrive3.vmdk](https://pastebin.com/PKv2ygMe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From another iteration of some Google searching, this link seemed like a good trail: [askubuntu - Grub2/ISOBoot#Example_ISO_Menuentries](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Example_ISO_Menuentries)

Led me here: [askubuntu - Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples#Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples#Gparted)

When working on that random other section of my boot device, I noticed the link in the example code, leading me to here: [ArchLinux - Multiboot USB drive - Fedora#Workstation_live_medium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Workstation_live_medium)

and it boots!

ArchLinux always has good wiki pages :)