# Can't find iso file from disk when installing centos 7

Tags: boot, usb, installation, operating-systems

I use the usb drive for install centos 7.

Centos 7 can't find the INSTALLATION SOURCE of the usb flash drive. How can fix it?

Comment: How did you made that USB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install fedora 12 iso file?](https://superuser.com/questions/94264/how-to-install-fedora-12-iso-file)

Answer (score 0):

The following link can provide the answer to your question:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56380

The CentOS directory is /media/RT0/IT/rob/centos6.7 (i.e where You unpacked the ISO), not /media/RT0/IT/rob/centos6.7/images/install.img.

Additionally You have to care if is live installation or from Disk.